# how to replicate oracle sql to amazon redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have been trying to replicate some oracle sql I have to redshift but I'm not too familiar with redshift, and I'm having some syntactical errors while replicating, I believe there's no `FORCE` in redshift, then how would i replicate this line of code from oracle sql to redshift sql. I have been getting syntax errors near FORCE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "dev"."daily_rates" ("FR_CURRENCY", "CURRENCY", "C_DATE", "C_RATE") AS
  SELECT DISTINCT GL.G_RATES.FR_CURRENCY, GL.G_RATES.CURRENCY, 
GL.G_RATES.C_DATE, GL.G_RATES.CRATE
FROM GL.G_RATES
WHERE GL.G_RATES.C_T='Corporate'
```

Answer (score 0):

`FORCE` makes objects without validating the query, if you are sure your query works you can ignore it.

[Amazon Redshift CREATE VIEW Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html)

`EDITIONABLE` is a feature in oracle that let you have several edition of same object in database and I don't know if any other DB engine out there has this feature, so I guess you have to remove those two options when you create your object in Redshift.

Comment: under which heading or line does it say that for force in the docs?

Comment: under `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING`